# DRUPAL: Dificuldade Backup e restauração

Tags: postgresql, linux, drupal

Sou novo utilizando o CMS Drupal e estou tendo uma dificuldade referente a restauração de backup. Criei um novo servidor para restaurar o backup que faço manualmente (dump do Postgres e copia do diretorio dentro do apache).

O server é um ORACLE Linux 7.3, APACHE 2, Postgres e drupal

Faço o backup normalmente e consigo restaurar, porém esta aparecendo a seguinte mensagem quando abro o site, que carrega normalmente.

> Warning: chmod(): Permission denied in event_css_add() (line 272 from
>   /var/www/html/com9dn/sites/all/modules/event_calendar_colors/event_calendar_colors.module)

com isso não consigo usar esse modulo, e nao estou conseguindo mais instalar nenhum modulo.

Ja coloquei as permissoes manualmente iguais as do servidor original e nao  mudou nada.

Comment: Faça um teste e dê um retorno do resultado: Primeiro tente colocar a permissão 777 no arquivo apontado pela msg de erro, se ainda assim continuar, tente colocar 777 no diretorio. Isso é só um teste, se funcionar, não deve ficar assim.

Comment: Não entendi a parte do faço o backup manualmente. Já leu ou ouviu falar sobre [Drush](https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/backup-migrate/bam-backup/)? Com o Drush é possível fazer e restaurar backups com digitação de poucas linhas de comando.

Answer (score 0):

O problema não tem relação com o banco de dados,mas sim com o sistema de arquivos.

O que acontece é que o módulo está tentando alterar as permissões da pasta  **event_calendar_colors** que está dentro da pasta de arquivos públicos do Drupal.

Se você não customizou o seu diretório de arquivos públicos ele deve ser:

```
/var/www/html/com9dn/sites/default/files
```

Neste diretório deve existir uma pasta chamada "event_calendar_colors" ou uma outra pasta files com o "event_calendar_colors" dentro dela.

Altere as permissões desta pasta para que o Drupal assuma o controle dela (é isto que o módulo está tentando fazer). O módulo está dando permissões 755, mas está tentando escrever na pasta, o que quer dizer que supõe que a pasta pertence ao usuário do Apache. Atribua a pasta ao usuário do apache com o comando:

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/html/com9dn/sites/default/files/ -R
```

Assim o Drupal assume o controle de toda a pasta "files". Você vai precisar disso de qualquer jeito...

Obs: estou supondo que o usuário que o Apache está usando é **apache**, que você está usando Drupal7 e que não alterou as configurações da sua pasta de arquivos públicos.